# Changes made to an object created outside of Vue component are not detected by Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a class Character :
`Character.ts`

```
    /// This is called when server responds
    public setAttributeByType(type: StatsTypes, value: number): void {
        switch (type) {
            case StatsTypes.STRENGTH:
            case StatsTypes.DEXTERITY:
            case StatsTypes.VITALITY:
            case StatsTypes.INTELIGENCE:
                this.stats[type] = value;
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
    ....
```

The class instance is created outside of Vue component in my "networking code":

```
    public static onStartGame(data:any):void {
        Player.character = new Character(data.data);
        Game.displayGamePage(PagesIndex.GAME_PAGE);
        requestAnimationFrame(Game.loop);
    }
```

And used in main component:
`Game.vue`

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import Player from '@/Player/player';
import SceneManager, { Scenes } from '@/Render/scene_manager';
import Scene from '@/Render/scene';
import MainScene from "@/Render/scenes/main";
import MapScene from "@/Render/scenes/map";
import Game from '@/game/game';

// Components
import VplayerBar from "@/vue/subs/playerBar.vue"
import Vcharacter from "@/vue/subs/character.vue"

export enum GamePages {
    MAIN_PAGE = 1,
    MAP_PAGE,
}

export default defineComponent({
    name: "game",
    components: {
        VplayerBar,
        Vcharacter,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            page: GamePages.MAIN_PAGE,
            scenes: Scenes,
            gamePages: GamePages,
            player: Player,
            character: Player.character, /* <------------ Reference to class */
            pages: {
                character: false,
            }
        }
    },
})
```

...which pass it down as a prop to `character.vue` component

```js
export default defineComponent({
    name: "character",
    props: {
        character: {  // <---- This prop does not change
            type: Character,
            required: true
        },
        toggleCharacter: {
            type: Function, 
            required: true
        }
    },
    components: {
        VBackpack,
        VInventory
    },
    data() {
        return {
            StatsTypes,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toglePage() {
            this.toggleCharacter()
        },
        getPortrait(isMobile:boolean = false) {
            return Character.getCharacterPortrait(this.character.faction, this.character.gender, isMobile);
        },
        addPoint(attribute:StatsTypes, value: number) {
            if (GKeyHandler.keys[Keys.SHIFT_LEFT])
                value = 10;

            CharacterHandler.addAttributePoint(Player.character, attribute, value);
            //this.character.stats[StatsTypes.STRENGTH] += 1; 
        }
    }
});
```

Problem is that whenever I change anything in character class instance outside the vue component (in my networking code) - for example `character.setAttributeByType(attribute, value)`, Vue does not see the change. If I do this directly inside `character.vue` component, it works (see commented code in `addPoint`)

I tried to use Proxy & Watch and it did not help.

Comment: Show us the code where you instantiate the class and "put it inside" Vue (parent component).

Comment: @MichalLevý Problém is that code is not instantiated inside Vue component. It is instantiated outside and only reference to this instance is placed in vue component

Game.vue -> character: Player.character, (Player.character is reference to the instance)
Game.vue binds character to the character.vue.

Instance is created when packet is received to start the game i.e when in custom handlers.

Comment: @MichalLevý The only work-around about it is to change prop values inside VUe component. Then it is working or force rerender which is not good. But changes inside class or outside the Vue component are not registered, Is there a way to watch those changes outside vue components?

Comment: Show the code! How is it "placed in vue component Game.vue" ?

Comment: @MichalLevý Might be enough, or i can provide full code in github if you would send me PM

Comment: Yes, it is enoug ...`Game.vue` is all I asked. Anyway, it should be in your question...not as answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is an "identity" issue described [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#proxy-vs-original-identity)

Vue 3 is using ES6 proxies to make objects reactive. If you do `const data = reactive(payload)`, the `data` is different object then `payload` (unlike in Vue 2 where the object was just modified with reactive setters/getters).

Same applies for Options API (you are using). If you do `character: Player.character` in `data()` the result is `this.character` (inside Vue component) is different object then `Player.character`. You can easily test it by doing `console.log(this.character === Player.character)` ...for example in `mounted()` - result will be `false`

As a result if you make any change using `this.character` (Vue reactive proxy), Vue will detect the change and rerender (and propagate the change to the original object) but if you change the original object `Player.character` the change is not detected by Vue...

Simple fix is to use Vue's [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#basic-reactivity-apis) which allows you to use Vue reactivity outside the Vue components.

```js
import { reactive } from `vue`

Player.character = reactive(new Character(data.data));
```

Now when you use `Player.character` to initialize `data()` in Vue component, Vue sees it is a reactive proxy already and do not wrap it in proxy again

Comment: Hi @michal, Is it possible solve this with option API? thanks

Comment: @SunuPinasthikaFajar To make an object reactive outside a Vue component? No, it's not possible with Options API. Is using Composition API a problem for you? Why ?

Comment: Well, we are using Nuxt 2.* here. and still wait and see to use composition API. (even there is a library for that) :) . but thanks for your concern and answer

Comment: @SunuPinasthikaFajar You can use [Vue.observable](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) for same thing in Vue 2.x

Comment: Although it should not be needed in Vue 2.x as it is using different mechanism for reactivity - instead of creating new object (proxy) it alters the existing objects with reactive getters/setters so there is no identity issue mentioned in my answer...