# Vue 3 does not update getter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am in the process of updating vue2 to vue3 but encounter this problem.
I have a service called `TService`

```ts
// T.ts
class T {
  public obj = { value: false };
  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.obj.value = !this.obj.value;
    }, 1000);
  }
}

const t = new T();
export { t as TService };
```

The service is very simple, it update it's `obj` value every 1 second.

Now come to the fun part

On vue2, I can do this:

```ts
<template>
  <div> {{ test }} </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { TService } from './T;

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  public obj = TService.obj;
  get test() {
    return this.obj.value;
  }
}
</script>
```

The `test` value updated on screen every 1sec and works as expected.
However, when I changed to vue3 with the below code, it does not work any more

```ts
<template>
  <div>{{ test }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { TService } from './T';

@Options({})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  public obj = TService.obj;
  get test() {
    return this.obj.value;
  }
}
</script>
```

Not sure what is going on and appreciate if anyone can fix my code.

I am using latest `vue` **3.1.5** and `vue-class-component` **8.0.0-rc.1**

Answer (score 0):

You probably should make it reactive so Vue knows its value can be updated,  [see here](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref)

Comment: Can u fix my code above for the vue3 version ?

Comment: Already try `public obj = reactive(TService.obj);` but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

The anwser can be found in this post:
[Changes made to an object created outside of Vue component are not detected by Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66912386/changes-made-to-an-object-created-outside-of-vue-component-are-not-detected-by-v)

Basically I will need to wrap reactive around my object in my service

```ts
import { reactive } from 'vue'; 

// T.ts
class T {
  public obj = reactive({ value: false });
  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.obj.value = !this.obj.value;
    }, 1000);
  }
}

const t = new T();
export { t as TService };
```